# Adding a Column to Membership Database

Tags: civimember

I would like to add a column to our database membership reports that would indicate the members' county.  At present, there is no column for this data.  Can I add one?  How do I do this?

Comment: Can you confirm that you want this data on the 'membership' record or the Contact record - eg should it simply be part of the 'address' or is it a standalone field

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to create a custom field against membership

Please follow the below link

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/

I guess this helps !!!